# How to assign the data of a centroid (marker) to the voronoi/thiessen polygon it belongs to? (R)

Tags: r, leaflet, r-sp, voronoi

In his [article](http://rpubs.com/walkerke/rstudio_gis) Kyle Walker showed a method to make Voronoi Polygons in Leaflet. He [drew Voronoi polygons around each starbucks coffeehouse in Fort Worth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOpe8.jpg) by means of the following code:

```
library(leaflet);    library(rgeos)
library(rgdal);    library(spatstat)
library(maptools)

starbucks <- read.csv('starbucks.csv')
fw <- subset(starbucks, City == 'Fort Worth')
coords <- cbind(fw$Longitude, fw$Latitude)
## Spatial points w/the WGS84 datum
sp_fw <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = coords, data = fw, 
                proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
sp_fw_proj <- spTransform(sp_fw, CRS("+init=epsg:26914"))
fw_coords <- sp_fw_proj@coords
## Create the window for the polygons
window <- owin(range(fw_coords[,1]), range(fw_coords[,2]))
## Create the polygons
d <- dirichlet(as.ppp(fw_coords, window))
## Convert to a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame and calculate an "area" field.  
dsp <- as(d, "SpatialPolygons")
dsp_df <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(dsp,
                                   data = data.frame(id =  1:length(dsp@polygons)))
proj4string(dsp_df) <- CRS("+init=epsg:26914")
dsp_df$area <- round((gArea(dsp_df, byid = TRUE) / 1000000), 1)
dsp_xy <- spTransform(dsp_df, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
## Map it!
leaflet() %>%
  addMarkers(data = fw, 
         lat = ~ Latitude, 
         lng = ~ Longitude, 
         popup = fw$Name) %>%
  addPolygons(data = dsp_xy, 
          color = "green", 
          fill = "green", 
          popup = paste0("Area: ", 
                         as.character(dsp_xy$area), 
                         " square km")) %>%
    addTiles()
```

I want to add an extra feature to his map: I want to assign a specific color to a polygon. This color depends on the characteristics of the nearest marker (the centroid).

for example, color every polygon with a starbucks centroid "green", and with a Dunkin' Donuts centroid "purple". (assuming that the starbucks.csv also includes coordinates of Dunkin' Donuts)

In other words, I want to merge the data of a centroid ("fw") with that of the polygon it belongs to ("dsp_xy").

Can someone help me out in this one?

Comment: We're not here to do your homework. What have you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck? What specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: Possibly, `sp::over` may be relevant here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `voronoi` function from the **dismo** package is what you need.  I'll also use this post to demo the new **sf** package for R.

Let's generate a reproducible fake dataset of Starbucks and Dunkin Donuts locations:

```
library(leaflet)
library(sf)
library(dismo)
library(sp)

set.seed(1983)

# Get some sample data

long <- sample(seq(-118.4, -118.2, 0.001), 50, replace = TRUE)

lat <- sample(seq(33.9, 34.1, 0.001), 50, replace = TRUE)

type <- sample(c("Starbucks", "Dunkin"), 50, replace = TRUE)
```

Next, let's create an `sf` data frame from our data, and take a look:

```
points <- data.frame(long = long, lat = lat, type = type) %>%
  st_as_sf(crs = 4326, coords = c("long", "lat"))

plot(points)
```

[image]

Next, we create the Voronoi polygons with the `voronoi` function from the **dismo** package, which is very straightforward, then give it the same coordinate system as our points.  In a real-world workflow, you should use a projected coordinate system, but I'll just use WGS84 (which the operations will assume to be planar) for illustration.  Also notice I'm going back and forth between **sf** and **sp** classes; the R world will fully support **sf** in time, but coercion is straightforward in the interim.

```
polys <- points %>%
  as("Spatial") %>%
  voronoi() %>%
  st_as_sf() %>%
  st_set_crs(., 4326)

plot(polys)
```

[image]

Now, visualize it with Leaflet using your desired colors:

```
pal <- colorFactor(c("purple", "green"), polys$type)

polys %>%
  leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
  addPolygons(fillColor = ~pal(type), weight = 0.5, color = "grey") %>%
  addCircleMarkers(data = points, label = ~type, color = ~pal(type))
```

[image]

We didn't need it here, but a function in **sf** that you'll want to know about as well is `st_join`, which handles spatial joins seamlessly and would work for the type of overlay you originally proposed.